# Taking powers of polytopes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, convex-polytopes, toric-varieties

I am not sure this is a well framed question but I would like to know if anything like "taking the power" of a polytope is known.

Imagine this situation where I want to think of such a thing : say one is given the unit square in the all-positive orthant of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Is there a ``simple" (hopefully piecewise linear!) map which will map this square to the square of side $2$ with its vertices at $(-1,-1),(-1,1),(1,1),(1,-1)$.

Had one started with a quarter of a unit disk then one could have taken the map $z^4 : \mathbb{C} \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ to get that to the unit disk about the origin. What is the closest analogue to this in the world of polytopes (and linear maps?)?

Comment: Isn't this just "dilation"?

Comment: Could you explicitly state which map you think does this? Also I used the square as an example. I am looking for something more general.

Comment: The map that dilates space by a factor of two maps the unit square in the positive orthant to the square with vertices $(0,0),(2,0),(0,2),(2,2)$. This is equivalent to your square via translation, and generally people only study polytopes up to translation (or even, affine equivalence) anyways. Dilation is central to Ehrhart theory, one main topic in the study of polytopes (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrhart_polynomial).

Comment: By the way, the product $P \times Q$ of two polytopes is a well-studied concept: if $P$ is of dimension $p$ and $Q$ is of dimension $q$, then $P\times Q$ is of dimension $p+q$. So there is already a notion of the "power" of a polytope, but this is different than what you want here because it increases the dimension.

Comment: I don't want to take products. Think of what the map $z^n$ does as a map from the complex plane to itself - it makes $n$ copies of the initial region and stiches them from end to end. One might take a Riemann surface view of this too. Is there an analogue to this in the world of polytopes?

Comment: Sorry, I should've said that polytopes are usually studied up to *unimodular* affine equivalence.

Comment: I don't think you'll have a good analog of $z \mapsto z^n$ for $d$-dimensional polytope $P$ unless $n = m^d$, in which case dilation by a factor of $m$ does take $n$ copies of $P$ and stitches them together.

Comment: For general polytopes how do you see this happenning? I am having a hard time imagining how a dilation by a factor of $m$ makes $m^d$ copies of a $d$ dimensional polytope.

Comment: Okay, you are right that it does not necessarily make $m^d$ copies, but of course the volume is equal to the volume of $m^d$ copies at least.

Comment: For a polytope $P$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ one could treat $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $\mathbb{C}$ and consider the "Minkowski power" $P^n := \{\prod_{j=1}^n z_j : z_j \in P\}$. But then the square of the unit square is the upper half of a lens shape centered at the origin.

Comment: An only slightly serious observation: taking the tropical structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$ would turn the usual "Minkowski sum" into a different notion of "Minkowski product" than the one I sketched above. Then the square of the unit square is a square with edge length 2.

Comment: How do you define the ``Minkowski product"?

Answer (score 2):

Given any $k$ and any polyheda $\newcommand{\bR}{\mathbb{R}}$ $P, Q\subset\bR^n$ with nonempty interiors  one can  easily   produce a $k:1$  covering $P\to Q$ branched over a codimension $2$-locus.

Here it goes. Fix  homeomorphisms $F_P: P\to C^{n-2}\times D^2$, $F_Q: Q\to C^{n-2}\times D^2$, where $C^m$ is  the cube $[-1,1]^m\subset\bR^n$ and $D^2$ is the unit disk in the plane.

Consider the canonical $k:1$ cover $S^1\to S^1$. Fix a triangulation $\newcommand{\eT}{\mathscr{T}}$ $\eT$ of $S^1$ and denote by $\tilde{\eT}$ its lift $p_k^{-1}(\eT)$. Then we can view $p_k$ as a $k:1$-simplicial covering. The triangulations $\eT$, $\tilde{\eT}$ of $S^1$ extend to triangulations of $D^2$, viewed as the cone over $S^1$.  The map $p_k$ then induces  a $k:1$   simplicial map $\beta_k:D^2\to D^2$ branched over the origin. Define

$$ \Psi_k: C^{n-2}\times D^2,\;\;\Psi_k(y,z)=(y,\beta_k(z)). $$

Then

$$ \Psi_k: F^{-1}_Q\circ\Phi_k\circ  F_P: P\to Q $$

is a $k:1$ map branched over $F_P^{-1}(C^{n-2}\times 0)$.

How  to  emulate this in the piecewise affine world?

Think of $\eT$ as the triangulation of the boundary $\newcommand{\pa}{\partial}$ $\pa \Pi_3$ of the regular $3$-gon $\Pi_3$ with vertices on $S^1$ and $\tilde{\eT}$ as the triangulation  defined by the  vertices of a regular $3k$-gon $\Pi_{3k}$.  Then $\beta_k$ can be viewed as a piecewise-affine $k:1$ covering map $\Pi_{3k}\to\Pi_3$, branched over the center of $\Pi_3$. Denote by $\Delta_m$  the $m$-simplex

$$  \{0\leq x_1\leq \cdots \leq x_m\leq 1\}\subset \bR^m. $$

Now  fix   piecewise-affine homeomorphisms

$$ F_P: P\to\Delta_{n-2}\times\Pi_{3k},\;\; F_Q: Q\to\Delta_{n-2}\times \Pi_{3}. $$

Comment: Thanks! Can you kindly let me know of a paper or book where I can read up more on this?

Comment: It's easier to prove a more general result: if $P_1,P_2$ are two $n$-dimensional  polytopes then there exists a piecewise affine  homeomorphism $F: P_1\to P_2$. Here's the main idea. Triangulate the boundaries of $P_i$. Think of them as (geodesic) triangulations of $S^{n-1}$. Then find a  geodesic triangulation  that is finer than both of these triangulations.